# How can I convert a string to a function in Python?

Tags: python, string, function

I have a function that I have as a string as follows :-

```
"def tree(inp):\n\tif inp = 'hello':\n\t\tprint('hello')\n\telse:\n\t\tprint('fake news')"
```

I want this function to save properly as a function as follows:

```
def tree(inp):
    if inp == 'hello':
        print('hello')
    else:
        print('fake news')
```

How can I take this string and save it as a function like this without constant copy pasting?

Comment: Use the eval function?

Comment: ^ this gives an error 'invalid syntax'

Comment: for starters, you are not naming your function.

Comment: ^ fixed this in the post and in my code. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: You would need `exec`, as a `def` statement is not an expression (which is what `eval` expects).

Comment: Why do you have a function definition in a string in the first place? Why not just define a module you can import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string itself contains the syntax error; you use `=` where you should have used `==`.

Having fixed that, you can use `exec`:

```
>>> fstr = "def tree(inp):\n\tif inp == 'hello':\n\t\tprint('hello')\n\telse:\n\t\tprint('fake news')"
>>> exec(fstr)
>>> tree("hello")
hello
>>> tree("bye")
fake news
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be it :

```
def tree(inp):
    if inp = 'hello':
        print('hello')
    else:
        print('fake news')
```